# Java script works in FIrefox, but in Safari and Chrome doesn't: error "Cannot access to uninitialized variable"

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, getelementbyid

```
Script works in Firefox, but in Safari and Chrome console it doesn't and shows error "Cannot access to uninitialized variable" in passLeft.textContent = "" line. Script is generating the password after pressing button in html script. I need this line to reset the output field every time after the button is pressed.


const characters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","~","`","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","-","+","=","{","[","}","]",",","|",":",";","<",">",".","?",
"/"];
let passLeft = document.getElementById("outputLeft")
let passRight = document.getElementById("outputRight")
passLeft.textContent = "*****"
passRight.textContent = "*****"
function generatePassword() {
    passLeft.textContent = ""
    passRight.textContent = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    let l = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length) // calls random array cell 
    passLeft.textContent += characters[l]
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    let l = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length) // calls random array cell 
    passRight.textContent += characters[l]
    } 
}
```

What ever value i put in passLeft.textContent = "" line, after pressing the button the error is the same:"Cannot access uninitialized variable." The error happens in Safari and Chrome, but in Firefox everything works ok.

This is my HTML file:

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@200;400;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Generate a <div class="rnd">random password</div></h1>
    <p> Never use insecure password again.</p>
    <button onclick="generatePassword()">Generate passwords</button>
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="outputLeft" class="output"></div>
        <div id="outputRight" class="output"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

[full error stack screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V91LO.png)

Comment: Please show the full error stack and point out what line and column the top stack frame refers to in relation to the code you posted.

Comment: What ever value i put in passLeft.textContent = "" line, after pressing the button the error is the same:"Cannot access uninitialized variable." The error happens in Safari and Chrome, but in Firefox everything works ok.

Comment: Yes but what is the stack belonging to the error?

Comment: I added error's screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code below, seems to be working fine.
When getting HTML elements make sure you have spelled `ID` tag right or it exist on you HTML document.

You can run your code below to test it.

```js
const characters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","~","`","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","-","+","=","{","[","}","]",",","|",":",";","<",">",".","?",
"/"];
let passLeft = document.getElementById("outputLeft")
let passRight = document.getElementById("outputRight")
passLeft.textContent = "*****"
passRight.textContent = "*****"
function generatePassword() {
    passLeft.textContent = ""
    passRight.textContent = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    let l = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length) // calls random array cell 
    passLeft.textContent += characters[l]
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    let l = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length) // calls random array cell 
    passRight.textContent += characters[l]
    } 
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Generate a <div class="rnd">random password</div></h1>
    <p> Never use insecure password again.</p>
    <button onclick="generatePassword()">Generate passwords</button>
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="outputLeft" class="output"></div>
        <div id="outputRight" class="output"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Above is my HTML Elements
[image]

Comment: I think the OP is calling `generatePassword` from an inline event handler (something like `<button onclick="generatePassword()">...</button>`)

Comment: @Titus Right let's try adding some button functions.

Comment: I added my HTML file

Comment: @HappyOtto Looks like you have a typographical error at line 1.
enclose the `Â` character inside `[]` array.
Refer to image above, that typo can make the javascript not to render properly.

Comment: Actually this was U+00a0 invisible character before bracket [ not inside array. I deleted and replaced with space. Now everything works!

Comment: Oh so it's showing different on your editor. Good to know it's finally working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this was U+00a0 invisible character in index.js before array bracket [ ]
I deleted and replaced with space. Now everything works!

Comment: Please add more details to make easier for others to understand the solution you found

Comment: In Visual Studio Code editor I deleted invisible character U+00a0, which was located in my 'index.js file right before array's square bracket, and replaced it with space. After that java script starts to work in Safari and Chrome browsers too.